# Singular value inequality for block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, block-matrices, singular-values

Suppose that $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, $m \geq n$, has the block form
$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 \\
A_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $A_1 \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and
$A_2 \in \mathbb{C}^{(m-n) \times n}$ is arbitrary. Let $\sigma_1(A_1)$, $\sigma_1(A_2)$, and $\sigma_1(A)$ be the largest singular values of $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A$ respectively. Similarly, let $\sigma_{min}(A_1)$, $\sigma_{\min}(A_2)$, and $\sigma_{\min}(A)$ be the smallest singular values of $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A$ respectively. Show that:

$$\sigma_{\min}(A_1)+\sigma_1(A_2) \geq \sigma_{\min}(A) \geq \max\{\sigma_{\min}(A_1),\sigma_{\min}(A_2)\} > 0$$

---

So far, I have shown that $\max\{\sigma_{\min}(A_1),\sigma_{\min}(A_2)\} > 0$. I want to use the fact that the largest singular value of matrix is its 2-norm and $$\|B^{-1}\|_2 = \frac{1}{\|B\|_2}$$ on $A_1$ since it is invertible. However, I don't know how to deal with $A_2$ since I have no information about it.

Comment: It is not generally true that $\|B^{-1}\|_2 = \frac 1{\|B\|_2}$.  We do, however, have $\|B^{-1}\|_2 \geq  \frac 1{\|B\|_2}$

Comment: By the way: using `\|A\|` instead of `||A||` gives you better norm-brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to note that $\sigma_{\min}(A) = \min_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$.  For the upper bound, note that
$$
\sigma_{\min}(A) = \min_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\| = \min_{\|x\| = 1} \left\|\pmatrix{A_1x\\A_2x}\right\| \leq\\
\min_{\|x\| = 1} \|A_1 x\| + \|A_2 x\| \leq\\ 
\min_{\|x\| = 1} \|A_1 x\| + \left(\max_{\|y\| = 1}\|A_2 y\|\right) =\\
\sigma_{\min}(A_1) + \sigma_{\max}(A_2)
$$
The proof of the lower bound is similar, but this time we use the inequality
$$
\left\|\pmatrix{A_1x\\ A_2x} \right\| \geq \max \{\|A_1x\|,\|A_2 x\|\}
$$
We only need the invertibility of $A_1$ to say that $\sigma_{\min}(A_1) > 0$.